# What is the control in the new Windows Store (Windows 8.1) for the top app bar?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

[image: Windows Store Top AppBar in full screen]

[image: Windows Store Top AppBar in snapped mode]

[image: Windows Store Top AppBar in snapped mode with menu]

I'd like to know if there is a control that can imitate the look and behavior of the AppBar that is in the current Windows Store for Windows 8.1.
Which control has such kind of paging? I am new to Windows 8 and 8.1 development. I have worked on Windows Phone 8.

Also, how to get that flyout menu that opens when there are subcategories in the menu item (third screenshot)? How do i get the small triangle?

Also, would this work on Windows 8.1 only or would it support windows 8 also??

Thank You for all help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation of App Bars is a built in component of Microsofts Windows Store Apps. 

[Quick Start: adding app bars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781232.aspx)

The Flyout control was introduced with Windows 8.1.

[Adding flyouts and menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn386878.aspx)